# Insert images to database error, when no image is selected

Tags: javascript, php

I use the following part of code to get the images from the user:

```
<p class = "images">
 <label align="center" class = 'odhgies' >select up to 4 images to insert: </label>

  <input type="file" name="image_1" id="image1" accept="image/*;capture=camera">    
  <input type="file" name="image_2" id="image2" accept="image/*;capture=camera">    
  <input type="file" name="image_3" id="image3" accept="image/*;capture=camera">    
  <input type="file" name="image_4" id="image4" accept="image/*;capture=camera">    

 <p>
```

The php where i take the inputs and store them to the database is the following:

```
$image1 = $_POST['image_1'];
$image2 = $_POST['image_2'];
$image3 = $_POST['image_3'];
$image4 = $_POST['image_4'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO images (image1,image2,image3,image4) VALUES ('$image1','$image2','$image3','$image4')" ;

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql); 
if($result) 
{
header("Location: success.php");
 exit;
} 
else
{  
header("Location: fail.php");
 exit;
    }
```

If i choose to upload at least one image everything works fine, I store the image i want and the rest are blank. The problem occurs when i choose to upload non, then i get an error saying that the image_1, image_2 etc. are Undefined indexes. Any idea waht is going on and how to solve it?

Ps: i know that i should not store images on my database but that is not the point right now. Thanks!

Comment: File uploads are accessed via `$_FILES`, not `$_POST` …

Comment: @CBroe Oh, I hadn't seen that the type was `file`, I will update my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$_POST` is an array and if you try to access an array location which doesn't exists php will throw an error, also you are open to [sql injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php).

You can use this to provide a default value to the `$image`s variable:

```
$image1 = isset($_POST['image_1']) ? $_POST['image_1'] : "null";
$image2 = isset($_POST['image_2']) ? $_POST['image_2'] : "null";
$image3 = isset($_POST['image_3']) ? $_POST['image_3'] : "null";
$image4 = isset($_POST['image_4']) ? $_POST['image_4'] : "null";
```

Take a look at [ternary operator here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php).

Also as CBroe noted your form field as type `file`, you have to access them via the `$_FILES` global:

```
$image1 = isset($_FILES['image_1']) ? $_FILES['image_1'] : "some default";
$image2 = isset($_FILES['image_2']) ? $_FILES['image_2'] : "some default";
$image3 = isset($_FILES['image_3']) ? $_FILES['image_3'] : "some default";
$image4 = isset($_FILES['image_4']) ? $_FILES['image_4'] : "some default";
```

Comment: Thanks that helped, i know i have to sanitize user input, and i will get on with it but i had to make it work that way first in order to get to the next step thanks very much!